# Getting Selected Text Events in Angular

Tags: angular, dom, dom-events

I am not sure if I understand how text selection works in an Angular application.  What I want to do is register a listener to get an event whenever the user selects some text inside the element.   If I code the element:

```
  <div [innerHTML]="doc.text"
       (selectstart)="evtSelection($event)"
       (selectionchange)="evtSelection($event)"
       (select)="evtSelection($event)"></div>
```

I only get selection "start" events and nothing else.   If I change the element to:

```
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="doc.text" name="text"
       (selectstart)="evtSelection($event)"
       (selectionchange)="evtSelection($event)"
       (select)="evtSelection($event)"></textarea>
```

then "select" events appear.  However that isn't usable because `textarea` won't apply formatting to the text -- you see just the raw HTML.

Is there some method to do this?

Comment: If div is not contenteditable, selection cannot change. Put contenteditable on the div and use (input) instead of (selectionchange)

Comment: @Vega interesting suggestion but it didn't work.   The user can now change the contents of the div (which I don't want) but aside from that I only get selectionstart events.

Comment: If you need to get the selection event, then (selectStart) works, right? I am not sure what you would like to do more or with. Because if you don't want to change the content, then why to listen to (selectionchange)?

Comment: Here a demo if you wish to show the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ls4czc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Any progress on the issue?

Comment: @Vega Actually yes.   It turns out that the elements like div do not generate selection events.   You can get it from the document object, then the event listener can check to see if the selected range is in the div element of interest.   Once I have it working I will post the solution.   Thanks for your help.